# Is it possible to extract Strings out of ListSelectionEvents in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, listselectionlistener

I am using JList of Strings in java swing. I want to have a ListSelectionListener which returns the String of the Listentry, that was selected by the user. But I can't reach the String itself. The only thing that I could find

```
private void registerListeners()
{
    gui.getListMeasurements().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event)
        {
            System.out.println(event.getSource());

        }
    });
}
```

Outputs the following 4 times: javax.swing.JList[,0,0,240x340,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=50331944,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,fixedCellHeight=-1,fixedCellWidth=-1,horizontalScrollIncrement=-1,selectionBackground=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],selectionForeground=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],visibleRowCount=8,layoutOrientation=0]

Nothing in this output refers to the String selected in the list. Neither can I find any useful method for the event. 
Is it possible to extract Strings the way I described?

Comment: Thanks! I reedited the source code

Comment: did you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html

Comment: Yes, couldnt find the answer there

Comment: really? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/ListSelectionDemoProject/src/events/ListSelectionDemo.java

Comment: So, `ListSelectionEvent` returns a reference to the `source` (which is probably the `JList`), the `firstIndex` and `lastIndex` which is been updated. Even with just the reference to the `JList` you should be able to obtain the currently selected item

Comment: Just read it again and couldnt find. It seems like you havent read it. Why do you ask rethoric questions if you clearly havent read the links you send?

Comment: As per the link **and** @MadProgrammer comment, you can make use of `firstIndex` and `lastIndex`

Comment: @Herr.Roehrig Please, understand, the problem isn't with ScaryWombat's attempts to help you, but you're lack of understanding of the problem - to be honest with you, this question is so simply answered with a small amount of research and some trial and error.  I'd recommend taking the linked source and running it and seeing what it generates as it will provide you with a deeper understanding of how the `ListSelectionListener` works and how you can get the information you need from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gui.getListMeasurements().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            return;
        }
        if (e.getSource() instanceof JList) {
            JList list = (JList) e.getSource();
            int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
            Object element = list.getModel().getElementAt(index);
            if (element instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("Selected value at " + index + " = " + element);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Helpful links:

- [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- [JavaDocs for `JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html)
- [How to Write a List Selection Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)
- [JavaDocs for `ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) and [`ListSelectionEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html)

Comment: Thanks mate. I appreciate your help!